# Color where @media (color) fails

Tags: css, colors, media-queries, usability

What is the result of applying color via CSS to devices for which [`@media (color)`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#color) fails? Is it akin to converting to grayscale? Or are some default non-colors used? Does blue convert to gray or invisible? How do `a`'s and `img`'s appear?

I imagine most `screen` devices would [support some degree of color](http://airve.com/mq/#mq-color) and that non-color would more apply to the `tty` type. Can anyone can drop some knowledge about what [types](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html#media-types) could lack color?

Answer (score 2):

What about a Kindle, e-ink display device or an early One Laptop per Child?

I would imaging that it would be up to the device to decide how to render the colors for images and the text.

Comment: Great idea—if anyone has one of please tell us how colors appear on websites, and whether the media query passes or not on http://airve.com/mq/#mq-color

Comment: Not sure if this is the case in all Kindles, but monochrome/color is reversed according to this article (its at the very end of the article):  http://blog.cloudfour.com/the-ems-have-it-proportional-media-queries-ftw/